# Seeking 3d rotation

Tags: matrices, 3d, rotations, rigid-transformation

I have a 3d rigid body rotation under which the unit vector $(0, 0, 1)$ becomes the unit vector $(n_x, n_y, n_z)$. I need to find what the vector $(w_x, w_y, 0)$ transforms to under that same rotation. All help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you say whether my edit captures your intent (especially with respect to the coordinate names)?

Comment: By the way, a single vector won't give you enough information to uniquely identify a rotation.  You'll need two.

Comment: The rotation is underspecified: there’s an infinite number of rotations that will map $(0,0,1)$ to some other unit vector. You need more information about the specific rotation being used.

Comment: If $(n_x,n_y,n_z)=(1,0,0)$ then the rotation is $90^\circ$ around $(0,1,0)$ or, equivalent, $270^\circ$ around $(0,-1,0)$. I don't think you need anything else.

Comment: @Andrei Using your example, every vector that lies on the plane $x-z=0$, i.e., on the angle bisector of $(0,0,1)$ and $(1,0,0)$, can serve as the axis of a rotation that maps $(0,0,1)$ to $(1,0,0)$. Each distinct rotation has a different image for  $(w_x,w_y,0)$. What information is there in the question that allows you to pick one as “the” rotation under discussion? Without further specifying the rotation used, the best one can do is to come up with a one-parameter family of images of $(w_x,w_y,0)$.

Comment: @amd you are right. My apologies

Comment: Brian - your edit captures my intent. Amd - you are right that the rotation is under specified - but I want the image under any one of those rotations

Answer (score 0):

A rotation can be described by an axis and an angle. To get the axis of rotation, just take the cross product of the initial and final state (I assume that $(n_x,n_y,n_z)\ne(0,0,\pm1)$), and then normalize the length to be $1$. The cross product and dot product will also give the angle of rotation.

Once you have these values, you can write the rotation matrix, according to [this formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle). Then just multiply the matrix with the $w$ vector.

Comment: You’re making an unwarranted assumption about the rotation. One could just as well choose a rotation through an angle of $\pi$ about the axis $(0,0,1)+(n_x,n_y,n_z)$.

Comment: I forgot about that.